# ID_FS_LABEL empty for luks volume

Tags: udev, luks, dmcrypt

I have an LUKS encrypted partition on a disk. I would like to label it and have it available at /dev/disk/by-label. 
The value used is ID_FS_LABEL to create the link in /dev/disk/by-label. That value can be extracted with vol_id.
The problem is that this value is empty. Is there a way for me to set this value somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problems come from the system not being up to date and using vol_id rather than blkid.

with

```
blkid -o list
```

it is possible to get the list of devices and their label.